redirect_uri_mismatch con Django Allauth al autenticar con Google
Sin razón aparente sale el error redirect_uri_mismach. Las URIs son iguales.
Estoy utilizando Django Allauth para autenticar usuarios con Google en mi aplicación, pero al intentar vincular una cuenta de Google, me encuentro con el error redirect_uri_mismatch. He revisado la configuración y las URIs de redirección, pero no logro solucionar el problema.
Cuando intento autenticarme, la URI de redirección a la que me envía es incorrecta y falta el subdominio, lo cual parece estar causando el problema. He intentado forzar el redirect_uri en la configuración de la cuenta social, pero el problema persiste. En los logs no veo ningún error.
Configuración en settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'accounts',
]

SITE_ID = 2

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware",
]

# Configuración de Google OAuth
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',  # Agrega los scopes que necesites
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
            'redirect_uri': "https://autotemplate.alanluque.com/accounts/google/login/callback/"
        },
        'OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED': True,
        'FETCH_USERINFO': True,
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

Descripción del problema:
Cuando intento autenticarme con Google, se produce el error redirect_uri_mismatch, y en la consola de Google veo que la URI de redirección que se está enviando es diferente a la que tengo configurada, entonces agregué la redirect_uri con la url correcta como se muestra arriba.
También probé correrlo a través del localhost con el mismo resultado.
He revisado y confirmado que las URIs de redirección en la consola de Google coinciden con las configuradas en mi aplicación.
¿Qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Capturas de pantalla:
config_uri:

error sin configurar el uri en senttigns:

error configurando el uri en senttings:

Cambié la redirect uri como se muestra arriba.

Intenté correrlo en el localhost con un proyecto en blanco de django con el mismo resultado. Verifiqué y las uris son iguales.
